# Typeorm - typed relations instead of strings

Tags: typeorm

A relation to be loaded is specified like this:

```
someRepo.findOne({relations: ["someRelation"]});
```

Naturally, the string is untyped and might causes troubles later on.

Is it possible to somehow specify relations in a manner that enforces types?

Comment: Maybe query builder would help you: `someRepo.createQueryBuilder('some_alias').leftJoin(AnotherEntity, 'another_alias').getOne()`

Answer (score 0):

I have settled for a static field that lists all relations, offers quite a bit of safety as well.

---

```
@Entity
class Post {
 static relations = {
   someField: "someField
 }

 @OneToOne...
 someField!: PostMetadata;
 /* ... */
}
```